# Is it possible to get the number of requests per second from AWS load balancer?

Tags: aws-sdk

Is it possible to get the number of requests sent to a load balancer in AWS?

I am trying to monitor the number of requests that our load balancers are receiving. Both ELB and Application Load Balance (alb).

Is there a way to do this from the cli? or the Javascript sdk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon CloudWatch has a `RequestCount` metric that measures "The number of requests received by the load balancer".

The Load Balancer can also generate [Access Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-access-logs.html) that provide detailed information about each request.

See:

- [CloudWatch Metrics for Your Classic Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html)
- [CloudWatch Metrics for Your Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html)